# FB Graph API OAuth 403 Error when posting to FB Page Wall

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

So i'm recieveing the following repsonse from the Graph API:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.}}
```

when checking the access token perms prior to the Graph call i get:

```
[manage_pages, publish_pages, public_profile, pages_show_list, email]
```

The app is in development mode and i'm the creator / admin of the page... the annoying thing is that this was working perfectly yesterday and only occurs once the user has been logged out and re-logged into the app.

Code for posting:

```
    if(!AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().contains("manage_pages")){
                                    Log.d("FBToken", "Requesting new token");
                                    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(auth.getUid()).child("FBToken");
                                    db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                            Date date = new Date(1764547200);
//TO GENERATE ACCESS PAGE ACCESS TOKEN

                                            AccessToken token = new AccessToken(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(),AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getApplicationId(),AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId(),Arrays.asList("manage_pages", "publish_pages"),null, AccessTokenSource.FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_SERVICE,
                                                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getExpires(),AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getLastRefresh(),date);
                                            AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(token);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                Log.d("FBToken", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions().toString());
                                new GraphRequest(
                                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                        graphRequest,
                                        params,
                                        HttpMethod.POST,
                                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                                               Log.d("FBPost",response.toString());
                                            }
                                        }
                                ).executeAsync();
```

I've debugged the access token in the Graph API Token Debugger and it comes back as a never expiring page token.  During the "Linking" process the user is requested to logInWithPermissions("manage_pages", "publish_pages") Does anyone have any idea where i may be going wrong here?

Comment: Which API call exactly gives you this response?

Comment: Within the Code for Posting area under the Log.d("FBPost", response.toString());

The post is also never posted to the FB Page

Comment: I don’t see how that API response would make any sense in that place, I’d expect that to only occur when the actual login functionality gets called. (But we don’t know what the exact parameters of your request there are.) I’d first of all try removing the app completely from the user’s settings, and then have them grant the permissions again afterwards, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: So I can still pull data from the FB page using the same access token (get post data from that page) but it just seems to be an issue when running the HttpMethod.POst